# SPEmailEventReceiver create item with relation to email

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, event-receivers, incoming-email

Im trying to implement custom `SPEmailEventReceiver`. I created class simular to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370749/getting-the-email-message-eml-as-an-attachment-to-sharepoint-listitem
Reciever is succesfuly called and list item is created. But the result is not the same as without receiver.

witout receiver: 
[image]

with receiver:
[image]

without receiver there is referece to email message from which was item created. I would like to get this result from `SPEmailEventReceiver`. Is there any option how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly found the solution.

Problem was that no all fields was filled. What brings me to soluion was customization of `DispForm` for `ListItem` in my *Discussion List*. I found that there is some hidden field and one of them is `EmailHeaders`. I fill this field with all headers form email in format `"{Name}:{Value}\n"`. And based on this field the relation to Email message was created.

This is my code:

```
public class Inbox_ITHD_EmailReciever : SPEmailEventReceiver
{
    public override void EmailReceived(SPList list, SPEmailMessage emailMessage, string receiverData)
    {
        try
        {
            SPListItem item = list.AddItem();

            Stream emailStream = emailMessage.GetMessageStream();
            byte[] emailAsBytes = new byte[emailStream.Length];
            emailStream.Read(emailAsBytes, 0, (int)emailStream.Length);
            item.Attachments.Add("Message.eml", emailAsBytes);

            SPEmailAttachmentCollection emailAttachments = emailMessage.Attachments;

            if (emailAttachments != null)
            {
                foreach (SPEmailAttachment emailAttachment in emailAttachments)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        byte[] emailAttachmentBytes = new byte[emailAttachment.ContentStream.Length];
                        emailAttachment.ContentStream.Read(emailAttachmentBytes, 0, emailAttachmentBytes.Length);
                        item.Attachments.Add(emailAttachment.FileName, emailAttachmentBytes);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //LOG
                    }
                }
            }

            m.FindEmailContent();

            item["EmailFrom"] = emailMessage.Sender;
            item["EmailSender"] = emailMessage.Sender;
            item["EmailTo"] = emailMessage.Headers["To"];
            item["EmailSubject"] = emailMessage.Headers["Subject"];
            item["Body"] = emailMessage.HtmlBody;

            item["Subject"] = emailMessage.Headers["Subject"];
            StringBuilder headers = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (SPEmailHeader h in emailMessage.Headers)
            {
                headers.AppendFormat("{0}:{1}\n", h.Name, h.Value);
            }
            item["EmailHeaders"] = headers.ToString();
            item.Update();
            list.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //LOG
        }
    }

    public static string StreamToString(Stream stream)
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

I think that with this approach also events will be created correctly in sharepoint(i dont test it yet).

Next problem which I faced was creation of mail body. If mail is only text or html there is no problem (`SPMailMessage` contains fiendy methods for this puprpose). Problem is embedded images, which are included in mail as a MIME part. `SPMailMessage` restricts access to Mail structure.

In debbufer i found that there is structure well created with *Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Mime* namespace, but im not possible o use private varialbe `m_mimemessage` in `SPMailMessage`. As i found there is no possiblity to include `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Mime` namespace to sharepoint project (if you know how please let me know).

What i have done is usage of [OpenPop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/). This library can split raw mail message to multiple parts and im possible to get attachements, embeded images and mail text. I add some functionality to lookup for storing embeded images in *discussion* attachements and change ContentID links in email message to http links to images. This approach is not described in code.